# Is it possible to animate the width of a UIButton of UIButtonStyleCustom type?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I have an animation on frame size which works fine when the UIButton is a UIButtonTypeRoundedRect. But has no visible affect when I am using a UIButtonStyleCustom with background image. My animation code is here:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"MyAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
CGRect tempFrame = myButton.frame;
tempFrame.size.width = tempFrame.size.width + 100.0f;
myButton.frame = tempFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:@"MyAnimation"];` is really `[UIView beginAnimations:@"MyAnimation" context:NULL];` (first parameter is animationID, NSString *; second - context, void *)?

Comment: @kpower I'm sorry for the typo, but it's still not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? Be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys, I finally resolve my problem. I subclassed `UIView` and added two `UIImageView`s and an `UIButton` to it. The animation is perfectly good now!

Here is the code:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NNAnimatableButton : UIView {

    UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    UIButton *button;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *button;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "NNAnimatableButton.h"

@implementation NNAnimatableButton

@synthesize backgroundImageView, imageView, button;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

        NSUInteger autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

        // Initialization code.
        backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = autoresizingMask;

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        imageView.autoresizingMask = autoresizingMask;
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.autoresizingMask = autoresizingMask;
        [button setFrame:rect];

        [self addSubview:backgroundImageView];
        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [self addSubview:button];

        [backgroundImageView release];
        [imageView release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [backgroundImageView release];
    [imageView release];
    [button release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example in my XCode. All works fine with both buttons. So some additional questions... Do you use `Background` or `Image`? What is view's mode (`Scale to Fill` or something else)? And where do you test your app (device or simulator, iphone 3 or iphone 4 or ...)?

Also make some checks. Check that myButton is connected in IB (maybe, you've created a new button and forgot to do this). Check that this code runs (maybe, you forgot connection to necessary touch action).

Comment: I use both Background and Image in Interface Builder, and the mode is Scale to Fill. It just changes the frame to the new one without any animation. I tested on both simulator and device, no luck.

Comment: I can use myButton.transform = CGAffileTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2); to scale the button, but I don't want my image to scale. The image should just be centered in the button view. Any help?

Comment: Try to use only Background (without Image).