# Animating a width change in a UIButton with a fixed center point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I've run into this problem a few times now, but I couldn't find an exact answer on it anywhere.

I want to animate a UIButton's change in width, similar the to effect in the App Store when you press the FREE button and it changes to INSTALL. After the touch, the button expands but doesn't move. In the app store, the button just expands to the left: I want my button to expand in both directions.

I've tried wrapping button.frame = ... or button.bounds = ... within a `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` block, but that doesn't work, even when I set the center within the block as well. No matter what I do, the button just seems to animation to a new position and then snap to the new width. Am I missing something here?

As an addendum, googling around turns up tons of people with similar problems, and often they just abandon whatever animation they were trying to do, which seems odd to me. This should be an easy solution, right? :)

Thanks!

Comment: I have also wasted countless hours trying to figure that out.  I just found this similar question, but haven't tried the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413496/is-it-possible-to-animate-the-width-of-a-uibutton-of-uibuttonstylecustom-type

Comment: hmm, that seems a little much to solve this. let me know if you try it and it works.

Comment: Ha! I was going to let *you* try it and let *me* know if it works :-). I don't currently have a need to animate a button size change (I gave up), but I'm still curious to find a solution, so I might try it some day.

Comment: Ah, I see. Very tricky. I'll let you know if I try it out, but it feels like overkill to build a custom ui component in order to handle animations on what's really a prettied-up uiview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested this and it works perfectly:

```
// Button setup (to keep text central during animation)
button.titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

// Animate
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
CGRect old = button.frame;
CGFloat diff = 60;
button.frame = CGRectMake(old.origin.x-diff/2.0, old.origin.y, old.size.width+diff, old.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, if your UIButton has an image, then you also need to set the autoresizingMask property of the button's imageView. In this example, both for height and width.

```
myButton.titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

myButton.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Also, as a side note, [UIView animateWithDuration... is way better than [UIView beginAnimations...